# Affine local property of reducedness

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $X$ is a scheme, and $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is an affine open sunset of $X$ with $(f_1\dots f_n)=A$. Then $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Spec}A_{f_i}=\operatorname{Spec}A$. Further assume that each $\operatorname{Spec}A_{f_i}$ is reduced, where we define reduced to mean that $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}(U)$ has no nonzero nilpotents for every open subset $U$ of $\operatorname{Spec}A$. I'd like to understand why this means that $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is also reduced.

So let $U$ be an open subset of $\operatorname{Spec}A$. Then $U$ is the union of some of the $\operatorname{Spec}A_{f_i}$. Then perhaps we could look at the restriction map $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}(U)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}(\operatorname{Spec}A_{f_i})$. However, I am not sure where to go from here. If we have some nilpotent $f\in\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}(U)$, then this restricts to an element in a reduced ring.

Comment: What's your definition of reduced? One standard definition is that all the stalks are reduced, which would resolve this pretty quickly.

Comment: @KReiser So then the stalks of each $\operatorname{Spec} A_{f_i}$ are reduced, and so any section of an open set of $\operatorname{Spec} A_{f_i}$ contains no nilpotents. But what about a general open set $U$ of $\operatorname{Spec} A$? I know it's a union of the $\operatorname{Spec} A_{f_i}$'s, and so any section on $U$ can be restricted to a section on the stalk due to the definition you give, and since these are reduced, $U$ is as well?

Comment: The definition I'm using isn't important here, the definition *you're using* is. Please add this to the post. What exactly is your definition of reduced?

Comment: @KReiser I have added the definition. I didn't realize it was nonstandard.

Comment: The issue isn't that your definition isn't standard (this definition is standard). The issue is that if you don't include your definition, it's difficult to give you a good answer. If I use an alternate definition you don't know yet without explaining how it connects to what you know, that's going to require some extra work (you comment, I comment, you comment, I edit, etc) to straighten everything out. It's best to avoid this by putting the relevant definitions in your post to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exercise**: $X$ being reduced (in the sense that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is a reduced ring for all open $U\subset X$) is equivalent to $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ being reduced for all points $x\in X$.

**Hint/Solution outline**:

> For $\Rightarrow$, consider what would happen if you had a nonzero nilpotent in the stalk and derive a contradiction. For $\Leftarrow$, embed $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ in the product of it's stalks.

With this in hand, since the stalk at $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec} A$ is the same as the stalk at $\mathfrak{p}_f \in\operatorname{Spec} A_f$, we have the result immediately.

Comment: +1, definitely the right way to do things. If one doesn't mind reinventing the wheel a little bit, then you can argue explicitly with a partition of unity argument. Namely, suppose $x \in A$ is a nilpotent element. Then $x$ is likewise nilpotent in each $A_{f_{i}}$, hence $0$, so it follows that there exists $k_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $xf_{i}^{k_{i}} = 0$. Since $(f_{1}^{k_{1}}, ..., f_{n}^{k_{n}}) = A$, there exist $y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n} \in A$ such that $f_{1}^{k_{1}}y_{1} + \cdots + f_{n}^{k_{n}}y_{n} = 1$. Multiplying both sides by $x$, we conclude $x = 0$.