# sufficient conditions for a scheme to be integral

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $X$ is a scheme and we have an open affine cover {$\operatorname{Spec} A_i$} of $X$, such that each $A_i$ is integral domain. Also we have that any intersection of $\operatorname{Spec} A_i$ with $\operatorname{Spec} A_j$ is non empty. Can we say that $X$ is integral scheme?

If not, any counter example? What other conditions do I need to make sure $X$ is integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's sufficient. Being reduced is a local property; you can check it on the stalk at each point, or on any affine open covering. (This is a good exercise in sheaf theory; [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3839058/41415) gives a hint on how to prove it.) That your hypotheses are sufficient for irreducibility is proved in [Stacks Project, Lemma 28.3.3 (tag 01OM)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01OM). Since a scheme is integral iff it's reduced and irreducible, this proves what you want.